# Equivalence of definitions of a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Fix a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. I have seen at various times the following definitions of a multivariate Gaussian distribution:

1. A random vector $$X=(X_1,\ldots,X_d):\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^d$$ is a *multivariate Gaussian* if $\sum_{i=0}^d c_i X_i$ is normally distributed for all $c_i\in\mathbb{R}$.
2. A random vector $$X=(X_1,\ldots,X_d):\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^d$$ is a *multivariate Gaussian* if there exist independent standard normal random variables $Y_1,\ldots,Y_d:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, a matrix $A\in\mathrm{M}_d(\mathbb{R})$, and a vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $$X=AY+v.$$

Now, it is clear that definition 2 implies definition 1, but I don't see why the converse should hold true. I suspect this might simply be an elementary linear algebra trick (such as Gaussian elimination), but I don't know for sure. My main difficulty is somehow obtaining independent random variables from $X_1,\ldots,X_d$ which may be dependent.

Comment: [Whitening transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation)

Comment: Now, suppose I've changed to coordinates in which $$\mathbb{E}[X]=0\in\mathbb{R}^d$$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(X)=I_d$ (and such that $X$ is normal according to definition 1). Does this suffice to tell me that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are all independent?

Comment: The individual $X_i$ are jointly normal, uncorrelated, and therefore indeed independent.

Comment: The important bit being *jointly normal*, as uncorrelated does not, in general, imply independent.

Comment: Do you have a good reference for that fact?

Comment: I expect one would find this in most references and textbooks. You might try the suggestions from Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncorrelated_random_variables#When_uncorrelatedness_implies_independence) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent).